# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'. Get "Requirement already satisfied" message after pip install numpy

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have two versions of Anaconda on my m/c Anaconda 3 & Anaconda 3.6. So while using Numpy i get the error message - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'. I know that is because of the two versions when i run "pip install numpy" - I get "Requirement already satisfied" message.

The command pip -V gives python 3.8. I am not sure what to do, what version to uninstall and how?

[image]

Comment: You have two different installations of Anaconda? You should get rid of one of them. Also, don't use the base environment for development, install the library in a new env. Finally, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Oh, and don't use pip inside of a Conda environment without a good reason, and following the proper procedure to do so safely.

Answer (score 0):

should use

```
conda install numpy
```

as for all conda library use `conda install` rather than pip install

Comment: Tried uninstalling and installing back again. Still getting same error.